# filtering an array of objects that contains an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

confusing title let me explain.

I have an array of categories and array of products.

the array of products is an array of objects, one of the keys is categories, which itself is an array of objects and one of the keys im interested in is title.

the array of categories is an array of objects too.

I want to filter the products array to return me just the products for my chosen category (which is set in state)

I've got this, however it does not work:

```
filterCategories = () => {
    return this.state.products.filter((product => {
      return product.categories.map((cat) => {
        cat.title == this.state.chosenCategory
      })
    }))
  }
```

this method seems like it should. to my knowledge, im filtering the products array by mapping over each product and then mapping over that products categories and checking if the category title is equal to the title in state. clearly I've gone wrong somewhere. can anyone see it?

sample data:

```
products = [
 {
  id: '123',
  title: 'wine',
  categories: [
   {title: 'drinks'}
  ]
 }
]

categories = [
   {
  id: '123',
  title: 'drinks'
 }
]
```

Comment: Please add some sample data from both arrays in your question.

Comment: @MohammadUsman added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to test whether *any* of the category titles match the chosenCategory: so, use the `some` method. Also, even better, if you're sure there's exactly one matching category, use `.find` instead of `filter`. Also make sure to return a value at the end of the internal function (which you aren't doing currently), or use an arrow function with implicit return:

```
filterCategories = () => (
  this.state.products.find((product) => (
    product.categories.some(({ title }) => (
      title === this.state.chosenCategory
    ))
  ))
)
```

Comment: `any` or `some`? :)

Comment: Thanks, my mistake

Comment: @CertainPerformance cheers. i'll accept this as it massively helped, although I've changed it slightly. I have to use filter because I need to return an array to map over again. but the implicit return stuff helped, why have you chucked in title like ` { title }` ?

Comment: @TheWalrus Destructuring when possible is helpful to reduce syntax noise - if you only need one particular property of an object, then just destructure that property in the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Filter callback function is a predicate, to test each element of the array.  you are not returning anything from the inner map function too, you must instead have a filter there like

```
filterCategories = () => {
    return this.state.products.filter((product => {
      return product.categories.filter((cat) => {
        return cat.title == this.state.chosenCategory
      })
    }))
  }
```